# compression library windows runtime

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, zlib

I am working in a project with existing C++ code and i'm missing zlib.h, windows doesn't support it so i need to find a way to do it with some other library.

For example this code doesn't work:

```
uLongf outLength = m_outLength; 

uncompress(reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(m_outBuf), &outLength,
    reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(m_inBuf), m_inLength);

m_outOffs = 0;
```

in black the errors

```
uLongf
uncompress
Bytef
```

Is there any way to do this with another library or in other way, or a way to port the `zlib` into the project. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

I hope someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

> I am working in a project with existing C++ code and i'm missing
>   zlib.h, windows doesn't support it so i need to find a way to do it
>   with some other library.

Are you sure of that? http://www.zlib.net/DLL_FAQ.txt

> - The exported symbols are exclusively defined in the source
>       files "zlib.h" and "zlib.def", found in an official zlib
>       source distribution.

You can use "ready" DLL http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm (Zlib for Windows) or build it by yourself: http://www.helyar.net/2010/compiling-zlib-lib-on-windows/

Comment: sorry i did not expecify WINDOWS RT (runtime) for windows phone. but i will try what you suggested me. thanks

Comment: Commenter has no idea that Windows (Phone) 8 does not allow you to compile .c files or compile old C syntax code (which is actually the real problem behind compiling zlib for W(P)8 ). The link is useless as only VS2012 knows how to properly link static libs with the adequate flags (windows 8 app support and Consume Windows Runtime extension)